# Laravel - change formular field border color if $error is true

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a formular and I want that the border-color changes to red if an $error occurs.

For example this field:

```
{!! Form::text('name1', old('name1', null), ['class' => 'form-control error', 'placeholder' => ' Your first name']) !!}
{!! $errors->first('name1','<span class="help-block error-text-color">:message</span>') !!}
```

my css:

```
.error 
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I want that if there is an $error for the name1 field, that the .error class css gets executed. If there isn't any $error, the form can stay like it is, without the .error class.

Does anybody now how I can make this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637788/how-can-i-color-input-fields-border-red-when-i-get-validation-error-laravel-5-3/46314977#46314977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 {!! Form::text('name1', old('name1', null), ['class' => 'form-control' . $errors->first('name1', ' error'), 'placeholder' => ' Your first name']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I update my post. Forgot your css class name. Try again